# What's the meaning of "On a hot skillet with beans"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, idioms-in-context

Shang Tsung: Would you consider serving a sorcerer?

Erron Black: *On a hot skillet with beans*, maybe.

Shang Tsung: I will not extend the offer twice.

resouce: https://mortalkombat.fandom.com/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_11_Intro_Dialogues

I found this on this website: [Meaning of the phrase 'hot off the skillet'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118074/meaning-of-the-phrase-hot-off-the-skillet)

But I still can't comprehend the dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offer is to work for a sorcerer.

The response is a suggestion that he might provide someone with the sorcerer's flesh for food -- cooked on a hot skillet with beans as a dish -- a very cynical and forceful rejection.

Comment: In other words, it's a pun on two senses of the word _serve_.

Comment: See also, "To Serve Man"